# Asp.net property value set to zero on button click

Tags: asp.net

On my ASP.net page I am assigning a session variable to a private property on `Page_Load`

```
private int userid{ get; set;} 

if (!IsPostBack)
{
   if (Session["userid"] != null)
   {
       userid= int.Parse(Session["userid"].ToString());
   }
}
```

And in my Add button click event I am using `userid`

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  doSomething(userid);
}
```

Initially the value is retrieved and stored in `userid` property but in `btnAdd_Click`, the `userid` becomes 0. I moved the code out of `if(!IsPostBack)` block, that fixed the problem but left me wondering what set my `userid` property to `zero` once it is already set on page load. Not clear whether on button click a new instance of the page is returned or what? Any guidance?

Answer (score 1):

You could just remove the stuff from the page load, since the data is in the session, and just change the property to the following:

```
private int userid{ get{ return int.Parse(Session["userid"].ToString()); } }
```